# Add any android-view to custom view

Tags: android, custom-component, seekbar

I have a simple View inside CustomDialog:

```
public class ColorPickerDialog extends Dialog 
{
    private static class ColorPickerView extends View
    {
        ColorPickerView(Context c, int color) 
        {
             super(c);
             //...
        }
        @Override 
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            //...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            setMeasuredDimension(CENTER_X*2, CENTER_Y*2);
        }
    }

    public ColorPickerDialog(Context context,
                             int initialColor) {
        super(context);
        mInitialColor = initialColor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(new ColorPickerView(getContext(), mInitialColor));
    }
}
```

How to add to this view SeekBar?

Comment: Do you want to add a `SeekBar` to `ColorPickerView` ? Or to your dialog ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a container class for your color picker and the seekbar.

For instance, if you want to layout them vertically:

```
private static class ColorPickerContainer extends LinearLayout {

    private ColorPickerView colorPicker;
    private SeekBar seekBar;

    public ColorPickerContainer(Context context, int initialColor) {
        super(context);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        colorPicker = new ColorPickerView(context, initialColor);
        addView(colorPicker);

        seekBar = new SeekBar(context);
        addView(seekBar);
    }

    public ColorPickerView getColorPicker() {
        return colorPicker;
    }

    public SeekBar getSeekBar() {
        return seekBar;
    }
}
```